# rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange: gives NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement read more functionality. On button click, i want to show the truncated text.

**My Problem is** i am getting NSInvalidArgument Exception with this code:

```
-(IBAction) ReadMore:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%d",[comm length]);
NSRange range = [comm rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){71, [comm length]}];
truncString = [comm substringWithRange:range];
NSLog(@"Welcome=%@",truncString);
}
```

I am getting comm length in log=291 & exception as:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The index 361 is invalid'

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range must not exceed the bounds of the receiver.Please read documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

try this:

```
NSRange range = [comm rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){71, [comm length]-71}];
```

Comment: Seriously? This is my same answer, 3 minutes after I wrote it. How come is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *comm = @"audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set audio session category set";
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[comm length]);
        NSRange range = [comm rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){71, [comm length]-71}];
        NSString  *truncString = [comm substringWithRange:range];
        NSLog(@"Welcome=%@",truncString);

Range should be within string length.
```